# What is solution of a homogenous second order linear differential equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, general-relativity

Function $y(x)$ and $g(x)$, defined on interval $[0,1]$, are related by linear differential equation that can be read as a second order or as a first order ODE

\begin{equation}
g~y’’+\frac{1}{2}~g’~y’+\frac{1}{4}~((g-1)/x)’~y~=~0, \tag{1}
\end{equation}
with boundary conditions
\begin{equation}
y(1)=y_1,~~~y’(1)=y’_1,~~~g(1)=g_1. \tag{2}
\end{equation}
I have found in the literature following method of obtaining solution -
one postulates some function, say $\Phi(x)$, and calls the function
\begin{equation}
y=a~\Phi(b~x), \tag{3}
\end{equation}
with
\begin{equation}
a\equiv\frac{y_1}{\Phi(b)},~~~b\equiv \frac{\Phi(b)}{\Phi'(b)}\frac{y'_1}{y_1}.  \tag{4}
\end{equation}
solution of equation $(1)$ to corresponding boundary conditions.

Using it one solves again equation $(1)$ this time for the function $g$ and states that the postulated function $y$ is the solution of the second order equation $(1)$ with variable coefficients defined by the function $g$.

I argue that it is not correct because the solution space of the second order differential equation is a two dimensional vector space with base built by two linearly independent particular solutions . The true solution has to be combination of them, say functions $\Phi(x)$ and $\Psi(x)$, where the second is derived from $\Phi(x)$ by the method of reduction order, both satisfying equation $(1)$, and the coefficients of the linear combination have to be determined by the boundary conditions $(2)$.
For me the solution looks like
\begin{equation}
y=c_1~\Phi(x)+c_2~\Psi(x), \tag{5}
\end{equation}

with
\begin{equation}
c_1~=~\frac{y_1~\Psi'_1-y'_1~\Psi_1}{\Phi_1~\Psi'_1-\Phi'_1~\Psi_1},~~~c_2~=~-\frac{y_1~\Phi'_1-y'_1~\Phi_1}{\Phi_1~\Psi'_1-\Phi'_1~\Psi_1}. \tag{6}
\end{equation}
I am not mathematician and the physicists that have used the method I claim to be wrong are numerous and well-known - therefore my doubts about it.

Comment: Your objection looks right.  I tried the example $g(x) = x$.  One solution is $\Phi(x) = J_0(2/\sqrt{x})$.  But then $a\Phi(bx)$ is not a solution for $b \ne 1$.  The only way I can think of to fix this would be when $g(x)$ has some very special property to make it work.

Comment: Yes, I am afraid I have explained my case not quite clear. The function $g(x)$ is not given but derived from equation $(1)$ (first order ODE on $g(x)$) for the postulated solution $(3)$ of the same equation $(1)$ but on $y$ (second order ODE). I will try to improve my question.

Comment: @GEdgar Hopefully, this time I have formulated my question more clearly, thanks for your comment.